# es6 logging function are undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out why i cannot call methods i have set in my classes. I have a class in es6

```
class school {
  constructor(size = '10', subjects = {
    math: 'green',
    physics: 'green',
    language: 'orange',
    history: null
  }) {
    this.size = size;
    this.subjects = subjects;
    this.classCode = null;
  }

  changeSubject(study) {
    this.classCode = this.subjects[study];
    if (study === 'math') {
      this.size += 1;
    }
  }
}

class room extends school {
  constructor(roomQty = 15, size, subjects) {
    super(size, subjects);
    this.roomQty = roomQty;
  }

  changeStudy(study) {
    super.changeStudy(study);
    if (study === 'math') {
      this.roomQty += 1;
    }
  }

  gatherStudents() {
    this.roomQty -= 3;
  }
}

const myRoom = new room(10, 4);
```

When I log this using console.log, I get an undefined message.

```
console.log(myRoom.changeStudy('language'));
console.log(myRoom.gatherStudents());
console.log(myRoom.changeStudy('math'));
```

How can i call these function and print the results to the console.

Comment: `super.changeStudy(study);` school does not implement it..

Comment: None of your methods does `return` anything. So what value do you expect `console.log()` should show?

Comment: @Thomas, i have forgotten to add return statements, sorry working too quickly.

Comment: Don't jump, do it step by step :D

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems with your code. The main problem was that your methods do not return anything and that your "super" Class did not implement the referenced method:

```js
class school {
  constructor(size = '10', subjects = {math: 'green', physics: 'green', language: 'orange', history: null}) {
  this.size = size;
  this.subjects = subjects;
  this.classCode = null;
  this.study = null
}

changeStudy(study) {
  this.study = study
}

changeSubject(study) {
  this.classCode = this.subjects[study];
    if (super.study === 'math') {
      this.size += 1;
    }
  }
}

class room extends school {
  constructor(roomQty = 15, size, subjects) {
    super(size, subjects);
    this.roomQty = roomQty;
  }
  changeStudy(study) {
    super.changeStudy(study);
    if (this.study === 'math') {
      return this.roomQty += 1;
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }

  gatherStudents() {
    return this.roomQty;
  }
} 

const myRoom = new room(10,4);

console.log(myRoom.changeStudy('language'));
console.log(myRoom.gatherStudents());
console.log(myRoom.changeStudy('math'));
```